# Change Data Without Refreshing Page

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I Have a profile page, with a status update/wall, I have limited "About" information on the page, I have text saying "More About Me .." which I would like to turn into a link, which when clicked, Hides the "wall" and replaces it with the "About" info. Im not sure how to do this, I Have tried a few JavaScript methods but they did not even work at all.

I have tried to make this work for a few days. Any help would be great!

Comment: i think you have to use Ajax to replace the anchor link with  'wall' without refresh page.

Comment: The wall would be the default display, I just want it so when clicked, it will hide the wall, and display the "more about" info

Comment: Please provide code you've tried..

Comment: Explain your problem better. If you need to retrieve data that you don't have at the moment you have to use AJAX to retrieve them as @Kaushalshah said. If you have the data already, you can use jQuery, javascript or wathever library you like. The problem is that there is too few information and thus we can't help you. Also, it would be really nice to see something you tryed already. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#more_about_me").on('click', function () {
    $("#wall").hide();
    $("#more_about_me").hide();
    $("#about_text").show();
});
$("#less_about_me").on('click', function () {
    $("#wall").show();
    $("#more_about_me").show();
    $("#about_text").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wall">
    <h3>Wall</h3>
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book  
</div>
<h3>About Me</h3>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text.
<a href="javascript:;" id="more_about_me">More About me</a>
<div id="about_text" style="display:none">
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    <a href="javascript:;" id="less_about_me">Less About me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be perfect, I can see the snippet it works, but i tried this on a test page, but it did not work, the link did nothing. im not too sure why

Comment: I have just tried on my system by creating test file it works for me..  You can download file from here : http://wikisend.com/download/458736/test.html Let me know this file works in your system or not.

Comment: That was perfect, My issue is that i had the script above the code rather than below it, Though i didn't think this would cause it to not run. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a pure js ajax call or  a jquery ajax call which is simpler.

```
<div id="about"><h2>About.....</h2></div>

<button>Load more</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

    $("#about").append("<div></div>"); //append a div inside hold the content to be loaded

    $("#about>div").load("url of file to be loaded"); // load the content into children div

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: without loading page replace div. not reloading

Comment: This is acctually almost identical to which i tried, tho on my console said "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

Comment: @ Joe Bills Make sure you are loading jquery library.

Comment: @ Kaushal Shah. Thanks to your observation. Please check the updated answer. It fixes your concern.

Comment: Thank you, Yes i did have the jquery library at the top of my page , This still does not work.

Comment: Can you out up a fiddle or a live link to demonstrate your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery ajax.

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="wall">
        My Wall Content
    </div>
    <div class="about-us-more" style="display:none;">
        Initially hidden
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <button type="button" id="load-more-about-us">More Info</button>
</div>
```

JQUERY AJAX

```
$("#load-more-about-us").click(function(){
    $.get("get_more_about_us.php", function(data, status){
        $(".wall").hide();
        $(".about-us-more").show();
    });
});
```